# Cannot import NavigationView in android

Tags: android

I am unable to import NavigationView in Android Studio.
It is giving error, unable to resolve NavigationView.

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
```

Here is my gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.www.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 5
        versionName "4.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.7'
}
```

Comment: Tried to rebuild the whole project? Clean project -> Rebuild? And all those gradle syncing stuff. If that doesn't help, bump the question with an update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though after exiting from android studio, I deleted .gradle and .idea folders with .iml files and it worked for me. Had tried the .idea and .iml deletion before asking this question but that didn't work. I think  your way was better, hadn't tried that.

Comment: Use Implementation instead of compile.